# How to make a Windows Service from .NET Core 2.1/2.2

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-core, windows-services

Recently I had a need to convert a .NET Core 2.1 or 2.2 console application into a Windows Service.

As I didn't have a requirement to port this process to Linux, I could dispense with the multiple platform solutions that I had seen on Stack Overflow that dealt with any combination of .NET Framework, .NET Standard and .NET Core.

Comment: Friendly reminder.  2.2 is NOT Long Term Support (LTS).  2.1 and 3.1 are LTS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In this post I will describe the steps required to set up a .NET Core 2.1 or 2.2 process as a Windows Service.

As I have no requirement for Linux, I could look for a solution that was Windows-specific.

A bit of digging turned up some posts from Steve Gordon (thanks!), in particular where he presents the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package and Windows hosting (click [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/running-net-core-generic-host-applications-as-a-windows-service) for post and [here](https://github.com/stevejgordon/IHostedServiceAsAService) for his GitHub sample).

Here are the steps required:

- First create a .NET Core console application.
- Set the language version to at least 7.1 to support async Task for the Main method.  (Access the language version from the project settings->Build->Advanced->Language Settings.
- Add the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting and the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController packages.
- Edit the project .csproj file and include in the PropertyGroup: <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
- Ensure you have in the PropertyGroup  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

Now go to Program.cs and copy the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AdvancedHost
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var isService = !(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"));

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<LoggingService>();
                });

            if (isService)
            {
                await builder.RunAsServiceAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code will support interactive debugging and production execution, and runs the example class LoggingService.

Here is a skeleton example of the service itself:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace AdvancedHost
{
    public class LoggingService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Startup code

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Stop timers, services
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Dispose of non-managed resources
        }
    }
}
```

The final two files necessary to complete the project:

#### File *ServiceBaseLifetime.cs*:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdvancedHost
{

    public class ServiceBaseLifetime : ServiceBase, IHostLifetime
    {
        private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> _delayStart = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        public ServiceBaseLifetime(IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
        {
            ApplicationLifetime = applicationLifetime ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(applicationLifetime));
        }

        private IApplicationLifetime ApplicationLifetime { get; }

        public Task WaitForStartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.Register(() => _delayStart.TrySetCanceled());
            ApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(Stop);

            new Thread(Run).Start(); // Otherwise this would block and prevent IHost.StartAsync from finishing.
            return _delayStart.Task;
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                Run(this); // This blocks until the service is stopped.
                _delayStart.TrySetException(new InvalidOperationException("Stopped without starting"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _delayStart.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Stop();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Called by base.Run when the service is ready to start.
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _delayStart.TrySetResult(null);
            base.OnStart(args);
        }

        // Called by base.Stop. This may be called multiple times by service Stop, ApplicationStopping, and StopAsync.
        // That's OK because StopApplication uses a CancellationTokenSource and prevents any recursion.
        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            ApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *ServiceBaseLifetimeHostExtensions.cs*:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AdvancedHost
{

    public static class ServiceBaseLifetimeHostExtensions
    {
        public static IHostBuilder UseServiceBaseLifetime(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        {
            return hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => services.AddSingleton<IHostLifetime, ServiceBaseLifetime>());
        }

        public static Task RunAsServiceAsync(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return hostBuilder.UseServiceBaseLifetime().Build().RunAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to install, run or delete the service I use the 'sc' utility:

```
sc create AdvancedHost binPath="C:\temp\AdvancedHost\AdvancedHost.exe"
```

where `AdvancedHost` is the service name and the value for `binPath` is the compiled executable.

Once the service is created, to start:

```
sc start AdvancedHost
```

To stop:

```
sc stop AdvancedHost
```

And finally to delete (once stopped):

```
sc delete AdvancedHost
```

There are many more features contained in sc; just type 'sc' alone on the command line.

The results of sc can be seen in the services Windows control panel.

Answer (score 4):

You no longer need to copy-paste a lot of code to do it.
All you need is to install the package [Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices)

Then:

- Append `UseWindowsService()` to the HostBuilder. This will also configure your application to use the EventLog logger.
- Change the SDK in your project to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker` (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">`).
- Make sure that the output project type is EXE file (`<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`)
- Append `<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` to the project file.

Debug your service like a regular console application, and then run `dotnet publish`, `sc create ...`, etc.

That's it.
This also works for .NET Core 3.0/3.1.
Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service).

The minimal code example is shown below.

#### .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="3.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### File *Program.cs*:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace NetcoreWindowsService
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddHostedService<MyService>())
                .UseWindowsService()
                .Build()
                .Run();
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *MyService.cs*:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NetcoreWindowsService
{
    internal class MyService : IHostedService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyService> _logger;

        public MyService(ILogger<MyService> logger) => _logger = logger;

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("The service has been started");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("The service has been stopped");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Top shelf has been a good "framework" for Windows Services.

It provides good functionality for the routine stuff that all windows services share.

Especially "install".

The basics are:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Topshelf/

Note the nuget above can be run under NetStandard2.0.

Now below.  You can create MyWindowsServiceExe.csproj .. and code it as an Exe/2.1 or Exe/3.1 (shown when you open up the csproj).  Note that 2.2 is not Long Term Support anymore and I would avoid writing new code to 2.2.  (off topic, but that link is https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core )

```
public class LoggingService : TopShelf.ServiceControl
{
private const string logFileFullName = @"C:\temp\servicelog.txt";

private void MyLogMe(string logMessage)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(logFileFullName));
    File.AppendAllText(logFileFullName, DateTime.UtcNow.ToLongTimeString() + " : " + logMessage + Environment.NewLine);
}

public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
{
    MyLogMe("Starting");
    return true;
}

public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
{
    MyLogMe("Stopping");
    return true;
}
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
HostFactory.Run(x =>
    {
        x.Service<LoggingService>();
        x.EnableServiceRecovery(r => r.RestartService(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(333)));
        x.SetServiceName("MyTestService");
        x.StartAutomatically();
     }
);
}
```

and build/publish it to windows:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release
```

and then the helper methods I mentioned

MyWindowsServiceExe.exe install

(now check windows-services under control panel to see it installed) (check "if crash, what should I do" tab as well).

and finally (another helper), you can STOP the the windows-service , you can run it from the command line (outside of windows-services)  This is my favorite for debugging.

MyWindowsServiceExe.exe start

Comment: I am upvoting Mark McWhirter's answer, because it is a good one.  This answer provided as an alternative and an "FYI" to TopShelf.